# Rails ActiveRecord joins the same table twice

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have problems with table join. ActiveRecord produces SQL which joins the same table twice. Assume we have models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characteristics
  has_many :properties, through: :characteristics
  has_many :values, through: :characteristics
end

class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characteristics
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characteristics
end

class Characteristic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :value
end
```

So I want to join both properties and values. `Product.joins(:properties).joins(:values)` will produce the next SQL:

```
SELECT `products`.*
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `characteristics` ON `characteristics`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
INNER JOIN `properties` ON `properties`.`id` = `characteristics`.`property_id`
INNER JOIN `characteristics` `characteristics_products_join` ON `characteristics_products_join`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
INNER JOIN `values` ON `values`.`id` = `characteristics_products_join`.`value_id`
```

There are two same joins to the table `characteristics`.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried: `Product.joins(characteristics: [:property, :value])`?

Comment: Thank you. It works. But if I have multiple through associations like `has_many :a`, `has_many :b, throught: :a`, `has_many :c, throught: :b` it will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join on the same table multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651003/how-to-join-on-the-same-table-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

I am in search for a more elegant solution and stumbled upon this. But this will work, just not as Rails-y as I'd like.

```
Product.joins(characteristics: :properties)
       .joins('INNER JOIN `characteristics` `characteristics_products_join` ON `characteristics_products_join`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`')
       .joins('INNER JOIN `values` ON `values`.`id` = `characteristics_products_join`.`value_id`')
```